# add an activity into another in android 2.1

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to add an activity into another activity?. I think TabHost can do this but I don't know how. In my application, I have a LinearLayout beside a list of button. I wanna add some activities (or intents) inside it then, I can make it visibility according to the clicked button.

Comment: have you thought about using fragments?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Comment: Fragments require API 11 or above. Is there any similar things in Android 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to MikeIsrael, I found [this library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html). Hope this helps.